# How Can I Prevent My Details Element From Shifting A Neighboring Div?

Tags: html, css

On the left I have a div with Details, and Summaries.

When I open the details element, the text expands, and the container shifts, causing my image in the right div to shift downwards.

Is this reasonably preventable?

How can I reasonably prevent it?

My code:

```
 <div id="left">

         <details>
         <summary>
            lorem
         </summary>
         <p class="general-text">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis totam quos illum. Obcaecati voluptates dicta voluptatibus sunt doloribus rem tempora.
         </p>
         </details>

         <details>
         <summary>
            lorem
         </summary>
         <p class="general-text">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis totam quos illum. Obcaecati voluptates dicta voluptatibus sunt doloribus rem tempora.
         </p>
         </details>

         <details>
         <summary>
            lorem
         </summary>
         <p class="general-text">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis totam quos illum. Obcaecati voluptates dicta voluptatibus sunt doloribus rem tempora.
         </p>
         </details>

         <details>
         <summary>
            lorem
         </summary>
         <p class="general-text">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis totam quos illum. Obcaecati voluptates dicta voluptatibus sunt doloribus rem tempora.
         </p>
         </details>
        

    <div id="right">
         <picture id="image-container">
            <img src="Resources/Images/myImage.jpg" alt="">
         </picture>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you put all relevant CSS and HTML in your question. Does this help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  
  <style>
    
    #left {
      float:left;
     width: 70%;
    }
    
    #right {
      float:right;
      width: 20%;
      
    }
    
  </style>
</head>
  
<body>
 <div id="left">

         <details>
         <summary>
            lorem
         </summary>
         <p class="general-text">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis totam quos illum. Obcaecati voluptates dicta voluptatibus sunt doloribus rem tempora.
         </p>
         </details>

         <details>
         <summary>
            lorem
         </summary>
         <p class="general-text">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis totam quos illum. Obcaecati voluptates dicta voluptatibus sunt doloribus rem tempora.
         </p>
         </details>

         <details>
         <summary>
            lorem
         </summary>
         <p class="general-text">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis totam quos illum. Obcaecati voluptates dicta voluptatibus sunt doloribus rem tempora.
         </p>
         </details>

         <details>
         <summary>
            lorem
         </summary>
         <p class="general-text">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis totam quos illum. Obcaecati voluptates dicta voluptatibus sunt doloribus rem tempora.
         </p>
         </details>
        
    </div>
    <div id="right">
         <picture id="image-container">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg" width="200px" alt="">
         </picture>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

or see here https://jsbin.com/qalimucoki/edit?html,output